# how to add horizontal axis labels to chart using macro

Tags: excel, vba

i created a chart using the following macro:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Sheet1'!$A$1:$A$13")
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
```

how to add horizontal axis label to the chart, because this code only adds my vertical columns.

i need to input horizontal rows as well.

I am Fairly new to macros, kindly help me out.

Comment: try to use macro recorder and see what happens when you manually add axis label.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is:

```
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "TheTitleIWant"
```

This first sets the chart to have an X axis title, then sets the text.

Comment: I dont want to add a title in the end, i want to set the X axis with data from my excel sheet. same way RangeActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Sheet1'!$A$1:$A$13")
works for Y axis, i want something for X axis. Is this Possible?